# Magento 2 getting wrong order and order id when select ship to multiple address

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, multishipping

I am using Magento 2.2.4, my problem is: 
I am using 2 events one page checkout success and sales order place after. 
In my controller I am getting order id from customer session using
`$orderIncrementId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId();`
Now when the flow goes with one page checkout everything works fine. 
But when I select ship to multiple addresses, event I used to get order id is sales order place after. 
The Id is random id from previous order. 
Also no payment details present in order collection

Comment: Have you unset your session in sales order place after event ?

Comment: No, is it required in the case of customer checkout session, because for normal flow it is working fine, only when ship to multiple address then order id is random previous order id

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use the observer in this case:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/GoogleAnalytics/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="googleanalytics_order_success" instance="Magento\GoogleAnalytics\Observer\SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="multishipping_checkout_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="googleanalytics_order_success" instance="Magento\GoogleAnalytics\Observer\SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Need to take a look at the Google Analytics for more details.

Comment: I'm already using observer

Comment: It should work. Could you show me your what you're trying with obsevers?

Comment: I used events.xml file similar to yours, I handled that event in observer  and from observer calling  my controller and using checkout session to get order Id

Comment: In the case of ship to multiple the order id is random previous order id. If I go with normal flow that is one page success event, everything working fine